# Laravel HomeController::showWelcome() does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I can get the following line in `routes.php` file working to see the welcome message:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

But the following line does not work:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return HomeController::showWelcome();
});
```

And I get the following error in the browser:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

What's wrong?

**Update:** After setting debug to true, I figured out the problem is this:

> Non-static method HomeController::showWelcome() should not be called statically

So in the HomeController.php, I change:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}
```

to:

```
static public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}
```

And the problem was fixed. I'm just not sure if this is the best workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

is default message when you work in production, to know better what is wrong you should turn on debug mode.

You can do this in:

```
app/config/app.php
```

by setting:

```
'debug' => true,
```

then reload the page to get some info.

Comment: Thank you! Figured out the problem.